# SQL MIN(), MAX(), and AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use the MIN, MAX, and AVG functions on a data set that it displays the title of a book from one table, "book" and then calculates the minimum, maximum, and average rating (on a scale from 1-10) for each title. My tables look like this:

**Book**

```
ISBN | Title
12345 | Title1
45678 | Title2
```

and 
**BookReview**

```
ISBN | Rating
12345 | 4
45678 | 7
12345 | 9
```

and I want the output to look like:

```
Title | Min Rating | Max Rating | Average Rating
```

I have tried using MIN(), MAX(), and AVG() and joining the two tables with INNER JOIN on the ISBN, but I have had no luck printing all of them out together. What I have now prints the lowest rating for all the books (it prints a 4 for each book) when I want it to print the lowest rating for each specific title. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You had no luck. That must be the problem.

Comment: are you using any `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join tables, select your columns and group by title:

```
SELECT   TITLE, MIN(RATING), MAX(RATING), AVG(RATING)
FROM     BOOK B
JOIN     BOOK REVIEW BR ON BR.ISBN = B.ISBN
GROUP BY TITLE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.Title, min(br.rating) as `Min Rating`,
    max(br.rating) as `Max Rating`, avg(br.rating) as `Average Rating`
from book b
inner join bookreview br on br.isbn = b.isbn
group by title
```